# docker sdk for container creation

Tags: docker, go, docker-ce, docker-ee

I am using go-sdk for docker to create a container by code along the following lines

```
resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: "alpine",
        Cmd:   []string{"echo", "hello world"},
    }, nil, nil, ""/* This is container name argument*/)
```

I understand that the argument that takes container name, if i use the same name twice, docker engine will reject it. Also unless a stopped container is removed, the name cannot be used. My question now is that if i send such a request back to back, is the server side code thread safe or it is possible that 2 such containers may come up for a short while? Basically I looked at the rest api server handler for that and did not understand much as to what the behavior will be.

Comment: The server code is thread-safe, and if you make two requests to create a container, you should always get two containers.  Is that the behavior you expect?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I might be sending create container request back to back with same name, will only one of them make it finally and all other be rejected as it is thread safe?

Comment: It’s just code, and the error is just an error.  What happens if you try it?

Comment: @DavidMaze, i used docker sdk create that gets triggered via aws sqs which can get replayed at random, if docker create rejects all but one command, I can rely on it. That was the intent of asking the Q. I still have to try but from docker code I must get this `ErrNameReserved = errors.New("name is reserved")`. Am I right so far and I can rely on docker was my Q